# transfer DTO to ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my data transfer object

```
public class LoadSourceDetail
{
  public string LoadSourceCode { get; set; }
  public string LoadSourceDesc { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<ReportingEntityDetail> ReportingEntity { get; set; }
}

public class ReportingEntityDetail
{
  public string ReportingEntityCode { get; set; }
  public string ReportingEntityDesc { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my ViewModel

```
public class LoadSourceViewModel
{
    #region Construction

        public LoadSourceViewModel ()
        {
        }

        public LoadSourceViewModel(LoadSourceDetail data)
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                LoadSourceCode = data.LoadSourceCode;
                LoadSourceDesc = data.LoadSourceDesc;
                ReportingEntity = // <-- ?  not sure how to do this 
            };
        }


    #endregion
    public string LoadSourceCode { get; set; }  
    public string LoadSourceDesc { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReportingEntityViewModel> ReportingEntity { get; set; }  
}

public class ReportingEntityViewModel 
{ 
    public string ReportingEntityCode { get; set; }
    public string ReportingEntityDesc { get; set; } 
}
```

}

I'm not sure how to transfer the data from the LoadSourceDetail ReportingEntity to the LoadSourceViewModel ReportingEntity.  I'm trying to transfer data from one IEnumerable to another IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without AutoMapper you will have to map each property one by one ,

Something like this :

```
  LoadSourceDetail obj = FillLoadSourceDetail ();// fill from source or somewhere

     // check for null before
    ReportingEntity = obj.ReportingEntity
                     .Select(x => new ReportingEntityViewModel() 
                        { 
                           ReportingEntityCode  = x.ReportingEntityCode,
                           ReportingEntityDesc  x.ReportingEntityDesc
                         })
                     .ToList(); // here is  'x' is of type ReportingEntityDetail
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use AutoMapper to do this:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

http://automapper.org/

You can easily map collections, see https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays

It would look something like this:

```
var viewLoadSources = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<LoadSourceDetail>, IEnumerable<LoadSourceViewModel>>(loadSources);
```

If you are using this in an MVC project I usually have an AutoMapper config in the App_Start that sets the configuration i.e. fields that do not match etc.

Comment: I use automapper for all my mappings to and from ViewModels

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to know how to do this "manually" without AutoMapper.

Comment: No problem, for me it would be an old fashioned DTO with a To() and From() method. I'll leave my answer there as this is the way I would do it now.

Comment: Is there a reason why not to use Automapper?? See this answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317583/passing-dto-to-my-viewmodels-constructor-to-map-properties and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995140/models-viewmodels-dtos-in-mvc-3-application?rq=1 for more

Comment: I'm not in charge of this project and I don't get to make those decisions and it was decided by more senior people not to use Automapper

Answer (score 0):

You could point it to the same `IEnumerable`:

```
ReportingEntity = data.ReportingEntity;
```

If you want to make a deep copy, you could use `ToList()`, or `ToArray()`:

```
ReportingEntity = data.ReportingEntity.ToList();
```

That will materialize the `IEnumerable` and store a snapshot in your view model.

Comment: I get an error  "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Augusta.Vault.ReportingEntityDetail>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Mdm.Web.ViewModels.Match.ReportingEntityViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"